# Adding variable to make dynamic Ruby statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having trouble creating a dynamic statement in a Rails ERB template. This is essentially what I'm trying to do:

```
<%= photo.@photo_col.url %>
```

This will make the statement dynamic based on this condition in the controller:

```
if !params[:cat]
    @my_photos = BusinessPhoto.where(contributor_id: session[:user_id])
    @photo_col = "business_photo"
elsif params[:cat] && params[:cat] == "event"
    @my_photos = EventPhoto.where(contributor_id: session[:user_id])
    @photo_col = "event_photo"
elsif params[:cat] && params[:cat] == "blog"
    @my_photos = BlogPhoto.where(contributor_id: session[:user_id])
    @photo_col = "post_photo"
end
```

Can anyone see a problem with this statement?

Comment: You could remove `params[:cat] &&` without breaking anything. It has no practical effect here.

Comment: Tweaked the code further for fun, if you're interested: https://gist.github.com/henrik/55066739a6e2147168a3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what `photo` is, so there might be a more straight forward way, but what you are trying to do is call a method by its name dynamically. You do that using [`public_send`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/public_send):

```
<%= photo.public_send(@photo_col).url %>
```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you! I knew it had to be something simple :)

Comment: Just be careful that the user can't set the `@photo_col` freely (i.e. never do `@photo_col = params[:col]`). If a user would pass in the column name "destroy", for example, they would cause the photo to be removed from the database :)

Comment: @Arun - if `photo` is an ActiveRecord, you might want to try `photo[@photo_col].url` instead